# Icon above text in a navbar menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to make a menu in my website, it will have an icon with text below, when i add the text it goes to the right and pushes the end `<li>` off

**Navbar with icon and no text**
[image: icon and no text]

**Navbar with text** (pushes last li off)
[image: icon with text]

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.adminNavigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.adminNavOptions {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 80px;
}
.adminNavOptions li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 62px;
  padding-left: 62px;
}
.adminNavOptions li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3"></div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="adminNavigation">
    <ul class="adminNavOptions">
      <li><i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i> test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT** - After adding Gleb Kemarsky's code it looks like this - the icon isn't vertically centered and the icon needs to be centered with the text so

```
ICONHERE
  txt
```

Also, the bar doesn't change width depending on the amount of li's I tried adding `width:auto;`
[image]

Comment: Try `.adminNavOptions .fa { display: block; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. **.adminNavigation**

   - Remove `display: table;`.
   - Assign zero value for the `padding-left` property.
2. **.adminNavOptions li**

   - Use `display: block; float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block;`.
   - Use `text-align: center; width: 16.66666667%;` instead of `padding-right: 62px; padding-left: 62px;`.
3. **icon**

   - The content of `<li>` is vertical aligned by the `line-height` property. So if you need to place an icon above the text, you need to change properties of `<li>` too. I've added the`.iconAbove` class for this purpose.
   - If you leave the icon to the left of the text, you can adjust vertical position of the icon by `position: relative; top: 9px;`.
4. **:hover**

   - Use contrast color for the text.
   - Set the `border-radius` property for the first `<li>` and for the last one.

Please check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.adminNavigation {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.adminNavOptions {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.adminNavOptions .fa {
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
}
.adminNavOptions .iconAbove {
  height: 80px;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-top: 11px;
}
.adminNavOptions .iconAbove .fa {
  display: block;      
  position: static;
}
.adminNavOptions li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16.66666667%;
}
.adminNavOptions li:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.adminNavOptions li:first-child:hover {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.adminNavOptions li:last-child:hover {
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
  <div class="adminNavigation">
    <ul class="adminNavOptions">
      <li class="iconAbove"><i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i> test</li>
      <li><i class="fa fa-play fa-3x"></i> test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your in depth answer, it's looking a lot better but if you see my edit, I have a few issues.

Comment: I managed to sort it, it was editing the width of `.adminNavOptions li`

Comment: @Kieron606 What kind of vertical alignment do you need? [A or B](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sho9U.png)?